# How to get text from cell to another in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Ok,

So I am trying to count a bunch of cells containing certain data which works fine. I am now trying to add date to that criteria which is typed into another cell. The issue with his is that the cells contain Date and Time and I only want to filter cells which "contain" a specific date.

This is my formula =COUNTIFS(Sheet3!G:G,"example",Sheet3!AC:AC,C50,Sheet3!AB:AB,A$48) Column AB being the date/time. I want to be able to right a date into A48 and then have a count of all cells that contain that date, but it wont work as there is also Time in the cell. Is there anyway of excluding the date?

I have also tried running a bit of code. This fixes my time issue, but the code doesn't stop when it encounters a blank cell. How could I make it do this? Or if I can solve the above I wont need the code at all. This is the code.

```
Sub ConvertDates()
'Updateby20140529
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address,      Type:=8)
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    Rng.Value = VBA.Int(Rng.Value)
    If IsEmpty(WorkRng) Then Exit Sub
Next
WorkRng.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
End Sub
```

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: if there is an formula in the cell, then excel will think it is not empty, so rather then checking if it is empty, check if it doesn't contain anything like so: change `If IsEmpty(WorkRng) Then Exit Sub` to `If WorkRng.Value = "" Then Exit Sub`

Comment: Thanks for your input Marco, I have yet to change the code but the below formula solved my problem. I am sure I will be able to implement this at a later date though and any help is good help. I will add it to my memory bank. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the OP has two questions:

> This fixes my time issue, but the code doesn't stop when it encounters
> a blank cell.
>
> *1) How could I make it do this?*
>
> *2) Or if I can solve the above I wont need the code at all.*

With the second question already answered by @pnuts by the formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet3!G:G,"example",Sheet3!AC:AC,C50,Sheet3!AB:AB,">="&A$48,Sheet3!AB:AB,"<"&A$48+1)
```

Let's look at the first question.

The macros does not stop for two reasons:

1. Instead of validating the cell value using `IsEmpty(Rng.Value2)`, it validates the entire range provided by the user using `IsEmpty(WorkRng)`
2. The validation occurred after the value of the cell is restated with `Rng.Value = VBA.Int(Rng.Value)` so the cell will never be empty at the time of validation.

This is your revised code, I have done also other small modifications.

```
Sub ConvertDates_Original()
Const kTitleId = "Kutools for Excel"
Dim Rng As Range, WorkRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", kTitleId, Selection.Address, Type:=8)
    If WorkRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        With Rng
            If IsEmpty(.Value2) Then Exit Sub
            .Value = Int(.Value2)
            .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    End With: Next
End Sub
```

Suggest to visit these pages to obtain a deeper understanding of the changes done:

[Range Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx), [Variables & Constants](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Variables-And-Constants.html)

Let me know of any question you might have about the code and changes done.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The first formula did solve my woes, but I am currently only doing small data sets and intend to begin dealing with much larger amounts of data so this is just a trial.

I haven't actually touched Excel in over 7 years and am just trying to remember whats what as I used to love a bit of VBA and its good to give it another go. Thank you for giving me some extra link, I found it very difficult to actually find any helpful sources on the web, as there is just SO much information out there.

Thanks again and I'm sure I'll be back with more questions.

Comment: Glad to help. Appreciate if you select one of the answers as the correct one in order to keep the site up to date. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet3!G:G,"example",Sheet3!AC:AC,C50,Sheet3!AB:AB,">="&A$48,Sheet3!AB:AB,"<"&A$48+1)
```

This should count based on any value in AB being greater than or equal to the date (without time) in A48 and less than one day later than that day - hence spanning whatever the times are.

Where I am at present this is equivalent to `27/11/2015` in A48 and:

```
">="42335,Sheet3!AB:AB,"<"42335+1
```

for the last part of the above formula - since time in Excel datetime serial is the decimal part of a day index.

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked great. Saved me a headache making it over complicated as well. Cheers mate.

Comment: I've actually since found that this formula DOES NOT seem to solve my issue. Once I entered data into the worksheet spanning dates from 21/11/2015 to 30/11/2015 the formula gave incorrect outputs.